# Windows for IoT Intel Galileo fails to image - Error Status -1

Tags: windows, intel, iot, intel-galileo

I tried to install Windows for IoT following these instructions

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/IBoughtAGalileo.htm

... and got the following error. Notice the Time zone of my laptop was changed from Central America (-6) to Pacific (-8)

```
C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads>rem ************************************************
**************************

C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads>rem ** Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, In
c.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads>rem ** Licensed under the BSD 2-Clause License.

C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads>rem ** See License.txt in the project root for licen
se information.

C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads>rem ************************************************
**************************

**** Temporary changing time zone to 'Pacific Standard Time'
**** Fat32 is local time based, and the images are created in a pacific time zon
e. If there is a mismatch Windows will bug check after 5 minutes.
File Not Found
**** Set-up work folder: C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply-BootMedia-10
277
**** Retrieveing C:\Users\janunezc\Downloads\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbu
ild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.wim
****          to C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply-BootMedia-10277

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Mounting image
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
**** Customizing image C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply-BootMedia-1027
7\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.wim
****        mounted at C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply-BootMedia-1027
7\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.wim.mount
**** ERROR: Failed to set Time Zone 'timeZone'
**** ERROR:    for image mounted at C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply-B
ootMedia-10277\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.wim
.mount
**** ERROR: Failed to customize image C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply
-BootMedia-10277\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.w
im
**** ERROR:                mounted at C:\Users\janunezc\AppData\Local\Temp\apply
-BootMedia-10277\9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.140731-1000_galileo_v1.w
im.mount

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Unmounting image
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
**** ERROR: Failed with status: -1
```

Comment: Run this from an elevated command prompt so it is allowed to change the timezone.  Or, you know, this is very raw and not tested that well outside of Redmond so just change the timezone on your machine before you start it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  the instructions for Win 7 as described [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/ImageOnWin7.htm):

- Download and install the [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) for Windows 8.1 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982)
- Select the “Deployment Tools” feature in the installer
- Locate the full path to the Dism.exe tool installed with the Windows ADK
- Using a text editor update each path reference of Dism.exe in apply-bootmedia.cmd to the full path reference of Dism.exe from the Windows ADK
- Save apply-bootmedia.cmd
- Continue with the “Updating your Intel Galileo” instructions

Example:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe" --> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\Dism.exe"
```